# Aggravating OpenGL Texture Issue

Tags: opengl, textures, fragment-shader

I'm having issues trying to get a texture loaded into VRAM.  I'm using OpenGL on Mac OS X.  I have geometry that I've successfully renderer by passing a color into my fragment shader.  However, as soon as I try to load a texture, no geometry gets rendered and I can only see the background color.  Here's my texture loading code:

```
char imageData[27] = {
    127, 127, 127,
    127, 127, 127,
    127, 127, 127,
    127, 127, 127,
    127, 127, 127,
    127, 127, 127,
    127, 127, 127,
    127, 127, 127,
    127, 127, 127,
};

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 3, 3, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

GLint uniform_location = glGetUniformLocation(bundle->GetShaderProgramID(), "texture");
std::cout << uniform_location <<std::endl;
glUniform1i(uniform_location, 0);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

And here's my fragment shader code:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    vec2 coord = vec2(0.5, 0.5);

    //gl_FragColor = vec4(coord, 0.0, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(texture, coord).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

I realize some of this code probably isn't necessary, but I've been trying everything I can think of.

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, always check errors with glGetError. If you have error, rendering may disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you don't have mipmapping off, and you did not specify mipmapping levels. So your texture is *incomplete*.

To turn it off on this texture object (to be done around the glTexImage2D call)

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

You do however realize that "everything breaks down" does not help at all figuring out what you see ? In general, a screenshot is worth a thousand words, but short of that, at least describing *how* it fails would help.

Comment: That's exactly my problem.  I can't believe it was that simple.  I've been working at this for two days now.  What I meant to say above is that the render window only displays the background color and nothing else, and I'll keep your suggestion in mind next time I ask a question.  Oh, and you might want to edit your answer so it has GL_TEXTURE_2D as the first argument.  Thanks again.

Comment: @helixed: also, only the background color is weird, as when you have incomplete textures, you should see the polygons as if the texture was not enabled. Was the background color black ? (it's also a good idea to pick a visibly different background colors)

Comment: Yes, the background color was black.  I didn't realize the default line color was black in OpenGL.  I'll change the background color the next time I have a problem.